# taking in parameter from instance variable in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add instance variable to a class method

Goal is to be able to return a boolean to the method - so it results in a true or false

its easy using local variables in the method (x,Y), but when I try to use the value from the instance variables, I get an error

This code runs fine with X and Y taken in as local variable parameter

```
 def isNumber(x, y):
        if x < 20 or y < 2 or y > 5 :
            result = True
            print("This is great")
        else:
            result = False
            print("This is not great")
        return result

    # For test purpose, I print. 

    print(isNumber(10, 5))
```

But when I try using the the instance variables (self.baseCost = 20000
        self.machineSalesPrice = 65000) it gives a syntax error

Here is the entire code. What goes wrong?

```
class BusinessModelType:

    def __init__(self,numberOfEmployees):


        self.baseCost = 20000
        self.machineSalesPrice = 65000

    # This Code works fine, as I'm using X and Y to test

    def isNumber(x, y):
        if x < 20 or y < 2 or y > 5 :
            result = True
            print("This is great")
        else:
            result = False
            print("This is not great")
        return result

    # For test purpose, I print. 

    print(isNumber(10, 5))


    # But when I start to use the two instance variables instead of X    and Y the code won't work 

    def isValue(self.baseCost, self.machineSalesPrice):
        if self.baseCost < 20 or self.machineSalesPrice < 2 or self.machineSalesPrice > 5 :
            result = True
            print("This is great")
        else:
            result = False
            print("This is not great")
        return result

    print(isValue())
```

File "", line 60
    def isValue(self.baseCost, self.machineSalesPrice):
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Goal is to be able to return a boolean to the method using the values from those instance variable

Comment: If you want values to come from already-existing instance variables, you don't need parameters at all: just refer to `self.baseCost`, etc., from within the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use class fields within a class method, pass the `self` argument to the class method. This will give you access to all class fields through `.` notation.

```
class BusinessModelType:

    def __init__(self, baseCost, machineSalesPrice):
        self.baseCost = baseCost
        self.machineSalesPrice = machineSalesPrice

    ...

    # pass `self` instead of `self.variable`
    # you can still access all variables
    def isValue(self):
        if self.baseCost < 20 or self.machineSalesPrice < 2 or self.machineSalesPrice > 5 :
            result = True
            print("This is great")
        else:
            result = False
            print("This is not great")
        return result

    ...
```

And then create a `BusinessModelType` object and call `isValue` on it

```
bmt = BusinessModelType(10, 20)
print(bmt.isValue())
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code you provided does not run. It gives a: NameError: 'IsValue' is not defined.
I dont understand that, as you dont need to define your method name...?

Comment: sorry, you're right. I'll edit. `isValue` is defined in the scope of the class `BusinessModelType`, so it won't work to just call that method. you must call it on an object of `BusinessModelType`

Comment: Thanks that did it. This gave me a lot better understanding of how stuff works. Thanks a lot :) first post on StackOverFlow :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. If you want to get the values from the instance, they don't need to be parameters at all. But as with any instance method, what *does* need to be a parameter is the `self` object.

```
def isValue(self):
    if self.baseCost < 20 or self.machineSalesPrice < 2 or self.machineSalesPrice > 5 :
        result = True
        print("This is great")
    else:
        result = False
        print("This is not great")
    return result
```